# JQuery Mobile forces refresh on setting URL Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I've been stuck trying to solve this. This is the case. I've built a desktop version of a website, where I used jQuery UI Tabs. On opening a tab I do a pushstate:

```
history.pushState(str, null, str);
```

This all works fine with no problems. The URL becomes page.html?var=xyz - beautiful. The user can use the back and forward button, nice. Now, I'm building a mobile version of this website and decided on using jQuery Mobile. However, it breaks this functionality.

I figured it was because of the routing, so I tried disabling it like so (loading it before jQuery mobile) :

```
 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
     $.mobile.ajaxEnabled            = false;
     $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled     = false;
     $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled   = false;
     $.mobile.pushStateEnabled       = false;
     $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
 });
```

However, this does nothing. When clicking the tabs jQuery Mobile (after a small delay), it still tries to go to the same page. I also tried adding these to the tabs links:

```
 rel="external" data-ajax="false"
```

But it still breaks. Anybody have any idea on how to disable this jQuery Mobile wanting to be the boss of the URL? I've narrowed it down that the pushState is what triggers the jQM reload. Any help would be greatly appreciated.